# Channel Entry Hooks not POST-ing fields

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, add-on-development, ee3, extension

EE 3.4.2

Working on an EE3 Extension.

I am able to utilize the `channel_form_entry_form_tagdata_start` to inject the custom field I need to for my Extension. This is a simple field (text) that is only being 'checked'. It isn't being added to the entry or the database.

The problem is when I try to capture that field using the `channel_form_submit_entry_start` hook, my injected field is nowhere to be found.

I can verify it is being added and rendered in the form Channel Entry form as needed, but nothing is passed.

Again, I don't need it to be added to the entry and it isn't being kept in the db. Should the submission not be passing the data in the POST??

---

In my method for the hook, I am simply dumping the results to see everything like this:

`var_dump($channel_form_obj);
        exit;`

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't show up in the `$channel_form_obj` only, or is it not being added to `$_POST` at all? Have you checked `$_POST` directly? Pretty sure that the object passed by the extension will already be sanitized to only include fields it knows about.

Comment: Derek, yea, I was making this harder on myself than I needed to. It was in the SG $_POST data. I was looking left when I should have been looking right.  ;)